# C++ read and write to same file using different streams

Tags: c++, io

I have two streams pointing to the same file. The first one is `std::ofstream os` and the second is `std::ifstream is`, both opened in binary mode.

I'm using `os` to create a new file. The file creation process requires me to (at times) read data that was written to the file by `os`. The `is` stream seeks to the needed position, reads some data, and then `os` does it's thing at its (distinct) offset and then flushes.

Is this legal to do? Will the streams stomp on each other?

Comment: Instead of flushing after every write, you can do `is.tie(&os)` which will do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Can´t quote any standard, but/because this is platform specific
(maybe exclusive access, buffering on different levels...)

You could just use a single `fstream` with `ios::in|ios::out`
and seek before every action.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because it will complicate things by jumping around (I would need a maintain stack of offsets) when doing a read or a write. I guess I'll see if the two stream version empirically works on my platform targets.